# The SonarQube code analysis task in our Azure Devops build pipeline yaml getting failed with storage issue in default location

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, azure-devops-extensions

Issue:- The SonarQube code analysis task in our Azure Devops build pipeline yaml getting failed with below error.

What we tried: We have SonarQube analysis task yaml in our AzureDevops pipeline and there is a maven task which using "clean verify" goal followed by the sonarqube task. when we execute this the maven task getyting failed with the below error.

> Failed to execute goal
> org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar on
> project: Unable to load component interface
> org.sonar.api.utils.TempFolder: Failed to create temporary folder in
> /home/vowne/.sonar: /home/vowne/.sonar/.sonartmp_xxxxxxx: No space
> left on device.

Not sure from where the sonarqube is taking the location from . its taking the users home directory now. /home/vowne. We have enough space in other location and would need to change the sonarqube temp location to there.

Is there something we can add to the maven task or sonar task to change the location of this temp ?

```
- task: SonarQubePrepare@4
    inputs:
      SonarQube: 'Sonarqube'
      ScannerMode: 'Other'
      extraProperties: |
          sonar.projectName=${{ parameters.myName }}
          sonar.coverage.xxxxxx.xmlReportPaths=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/site/xxxxx/xxxxx.xml
```

Here can we add an extra property to the sonar task like `sonar.userHome=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`

or maven task need to change ""goal"  from "clean verify" to some customised values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [source code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/900af07a23832dc8357eb49c3dd997976686ff29/sonar-scanner-engine/src/main/java/org/sonar/scanner/bootstrap/GlobalTempFolderProvider.java#L62) this path is derived from the following properties:

- `sonar.globalWorking.directory` system property (resolved relative to settings below if not absolute),
- `sonar.userHome` system property,
- `SONAR_USER_HOME` environment variable,
- `.sonar` directory under `user.home` system property.

It seems that the last case matches your scenario. Try to set one of the above settings to select different location instead of `~/.sonar`.

Comment: We are using AzureDevops pipeline task template for sonarqube. So not sure where to add this value